# How to add a matrix and a vector in MATLAB considering positions

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, sum, vectorization

I have this little problem and I hope that you can help me.

My question is about if there is someway to make this operation in **MATLAB**:

Suppose this matrix called A(4x3):

`A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;8 9 1];`

and this vector array called B (4x1):

`B=[1;3;5;0];`

Now the operation that I want to make is kinda simple: A+B=C, where C is:

```
 A      +  B   =     C
```

`C=[2 3 4;7 8 9;12 13 14;8 9 1];`

As you can see, the first row of the matrix C is the sum between the first row of matrix A with the first value of the vector B, and it continues.

I know how to make it easily using a "for" but I want to know if there's a way to make it faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** [*Apply element-by-element binary operation to two arrays with singleton expansion enabled*] with a function handle `@plus` might just work for you. It lets `B` expand onto the second dimension as needed for operating with `A` which is already a 2D matrix and thus giving you the desired "summation" output -

```
bsxfun(@plus,A,B)
```